# javascript call web api from remote server

Tags: javascript, api, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have this code

but it run on localhost successfully but when I tried it on remote it refused

```
    var parameters = { domainGuid:"test1",type:"testtype"    };

    var url = "http://remote_server/api/controller_name/test_api";
 //   jQuery.support.cors = true;
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: parameters,
        async: false,
        dataType: "json",
        crossDomain: true,
        success: get_all_videos_success,
        error: get_all_videos_error
    });
```

it go to error function every time

Comment: Can you post the error you get?

Comment: No error it just go to error function each time and responce always has network error

Comment: im willing to bet this is a CORS issue.

Comment: @Mike_G So, what Shall I do

Comment: I am assuming you control the remote server, and assuming that the remote server is hosting an Asp.Net Web Api application, and assuming you are getting a CORS error in the browser but just aren't seeing it.  If my assumptions are correct, then I would enable CORS for the web app.  http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Comment: I added the CORS but still same thing... Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried switching your dataType from json to jsonp?